# load <option> with ajax when open <select>

Tags: jquery, ajax

I've a long list of items in a select box (more or less 6000). When I load the PHP page, it takes a while. Because of the fact, that this `<select>` is  very rarely chanced, I would like to load the `<option>`´s just in case, that I need them.

I would call the jquery function

```
$("#select_id").load("code.php").change();
```

But which handler should I use? And how can I shot the user, that this  is loading for 1-2 sec.?

Comment: "how can I shot the user" ? with a gun ? joke .

Comment: How would someone even use a select box that large? Wouldn't it be easier to have the selector for this on another page, perhaps with paging options for the values?

Comment: i would recommend to use http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/index.html for such a large list.

Comment: You should bind to the `focus` event, but as others have said, how is anyone going to use a 6000+ select element?

Comment: That's where autocomplete text boxes come handy.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var $select = $('#select_id');
$select.load('code.php', function () {
    $select.change(function() {
      alert('Handler for .change() called.');
    });
});
```

We have used the **Callback Function** here. So, the code `select.change()` will be executed after post-processing and HTML insertion has been performed.